# Add product to cart programatically for Magento 2.4.x

Tags: magento2

I am creating a controller in custom module which will grab the product id from url and add that product to cart.
I see a number of tutorials using

> Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart

And for controller extending

> Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action

But both of these classes are deprecated for new versions of Magento 2.

I am currently working with Magento 2.4.x.

Please help me how to add product to cart using frontend controller for Magento 2 latest versions.

Comment: Hopefully this should work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297985/magento-2-add-product-to-cart-programmatically-with-custom-options

Comment: Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart this is showing as deprecated

Comment: dont know what happens but it is working fine, if you still having issues then I Posted a answer below

Answer (score -1):

Just copy paste this code in file and place it inside `pub/`. Please find below code -

```
<?php

try {
require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

$objectManagerFactory = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::createObjectManagerFactory(BP, []);

$obj = $objectManagerFactory->create([]);    
$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('global');

$productId = 497;

$product = $obj->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);

$formKey = $obj->create('\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey')->getFormKey();  

$cart = $obj->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');    
$params = array();      
$options = array();
$params['form_key'] = $formKey;
$params['qty'] = 1;
$params['product'] = 497;

foreach ($product->getOptions() as $o) 
{         
    foreach ($o->getValues() as $value) 
    {
        $options[$value['option_id']] = $value['option_type_id'];
    }           
}

$params['options'] = $options;
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
  echo $e;
}
```